# Why does iptables output to /dev/console?

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, syslog

For some reason I see the output from this iptables rule

```
$IPT -A FORWARD --jump LOG
$IPT -A FORWARD --jump ACCEPT
```

on the console eventhough I have disabled `kern` in `/etc/syslog.conf`

```
#kern.*                                                 /dev/console
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure
mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron
*.emerg                                                 *
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log
```

But for some reason I still get the output on the console.

Does anyone know why that is?

**Update**

Could it have something to do with `klogd`?

```
# service syslog status
syslogd (pid  2099) is running...
klogd (pid  2102) is running...
```

Comment: You HUPed syslogd, right?

Comment: You probably have another line that is matching. Please paste your entire syslogd.conf.

Comment: @JeffFerland The post is now updated with the enture syslogd.conf

Comment: @cjc What does "HUPed" mean? I have just edited `/etc/syslog.conf` and then `service syslog restart`

Comment: @Sandra: it means reloading the syslogd process by sending SIGHUP or calling `service syslog reload`. Restart should be OK also.

Comment: "HUP" = "kill -HUP".

Comment: @Khaled I see. Then yes. I have just `service syslog restart`. Is a reboot required when changing `kern.*`?

Comment: What linux are you running?

Comment: @cjc Is is a CentOS 5.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're running a RHEL-derived linux.

Take a look at:

http://blog.marioandwindy.com/tag/klogd_options/

So, you will need to edit /etc/sysconfig/syslog and edit the KLOGD_OPTIONS line.

After that, you'll need to run `service syslog restart` (the options set in /etc/sysconfig/syslog are startup command line options for the syslogd and klogd processes, and are separate from the configuration file).

As a side note, I have this in my /etc/sysconfig/syslog file:

```
KLOGD_OPTIONS="-x -c 1"
```

Basically, we're setting level for the console message from the kernel to priority level 1.